# Route traffic to container using Azure Application Gateway Path-based

Tags: azure, routes, containers, virtual-machine, azure-application-gateway

I'm currently working with Azure Application Gateway and Docker containers(AKS); and would like to route traffic to my backend pool using path-based rules.

I heard that path-based rules and containers don't have a really good compatibility. Is this true?
If this is not a good approach, hosting the containers in a Virtual Machine will be better?

What I want to do is something like this:

```
...../pathA -> containerA
...../pathB -> containerB
...../pathC -> containerC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd needed to do this without using a readymade solution - it would be a bit of a pain, however there is a [solution](https://github.com/Azure/application-gateway-kubernetes-ingress) for this specific problem already.

Although, I would never recommend using this solution, I'd recommend using [nginx ingress](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx) or any other reasonable ingress controller.

The approach is more or less the same:

1. you install ingress controller
2. you create ingress definitions to repeat your desired routing pattern with Application Gateway

ps. I'f you'd be using the solution proposed you'd be using ingress resources either way, so not sure if its worth using Application Gateway for that. Probably would be easier\cheaper to just use regular ingress.

Comment: The Application Gateway is the entrypoint of the whole system, so it is a required item.
I will try the ngix ingress method. If doesn't work well, I will need to host the app in a VM instead of containers.

Comment: I would advise against using the same application gateway for AKS and for other stuff, tbh

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I will use AKS or VM not both